# Call a function after inserting a newline

Tags: autocmd, insert-mode

In insert mode, I want to call some function if `<Enter>` was typed.

I tried `InsertCharPre` but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `InsertCharPre` event doesn't trigger for characters such as `<Enter>` or `<Tab>`.

Instead, use an insert-mode mapping to call a function after pressing `<Enter>`:

```
inoremap <CR> <CR><C-O>:call MyFunc()<CR>
```

Or use a `map-<expr>` and have your function return the string to be inserted. Start that with `"\r"` if you'd like to preserve the newline that would be inserted.

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> MyFunc()
```

See also:

- `:help :inoremap`
- `:help i_CTRL-O`
- `:help :map-<expr>`

Comment: Didn't know `InsertCharPre` event doesn't trigger for characters such as <Enter> or <Tab>.  Thx.